# In C# how does one access the elements of an array of control labels created at runtime?

Tags: c#

Over the years I've done a significant amount of programming in various forms of BASIC, including Visual Basic. When it comes to C# I'm quite confused. Below is the form load code for a mastermind program I am creating in C#. Everything works, until I try to create my marking routine.

```
 public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //int columns = 14;
        Label[,] board = new Label[5,14];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++)
            {
                board[i,j] = new Label();
                board[i,j].AutoSize = false;
                board[i,j].Size = Dummy.Size;
                board[i,j].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                board[i,j].BackColor = Color.Beige;
                board[i,j].Location = new Point(i * Dummy.Width+2, j * Dummy.Height+2);
                board[i,j].Name = "board" + i.ToString() + "," + j.ToString();
                board[i,j].Width = Dummy.Width - 4;
                board[i,j].Height = Dummy.Height - 4;
                board[i,j].TabIndex = 0;
                //board[i][j].Text = i.ToString() +" "+ j.ToString();
                panel2.Controls.Add(board[i,j]);
                board[i,j].Click += new EventHandler(Label1_Click);
            }        
            P2.Click += new EventHandler(P1_Click);
            P3.Click += new EventHandler(P1_Click);
            P4.Click += new EventHandler(P1_Click);
            P5.Click += new EventHandler(P1_Click);
            P6.Click += new EventHandler(P1_Click);
            P7.Click += new EventHandler(P1_Click);
            P8.Click += new EventHandler(P1_Click);
        }
        int marker = 14;
        int each = 5;
        Label[,] mark = new Label[each,marker];
        // Instantiating all the buttons in the array
        for (int i = 0; i < each; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < marker; j++)
            {
                mark[i, j] = new Label();
                mark[i, j].AutoSize=false;
                mark[i, j].Size = Minnie.Size;
                mark[i, j].BorderStyle = Minnie.BorderStyle;
                mark[i, j].BackColor = Color.Blue;
                mark[i, j].Left = i * (Minnie.Width+2)+3;
                mark[i, j].Top = j * Dummy.Height+10;
                panel3.Controls.Add(mark[i, j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

This creates the playing 'holes' for guesses, and smaller marking 'holes' in panels 2 and 3, respectively. The playing part works fine as I have a selection panel that allows the user to choose colors and then 'place' the colors by clicking the board holes array. The various colours are matched by numbers which I append to the .Tag of board elements when they are clicked. The diffculty comes when I try to read the .Tags to assess the guesses for marking. Here is the code that is not working:

```
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int r;
        for (r=0;r<5;r++) {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + board[0,r].Tag;
            //board[0, r].BackColor = Color.Azure;
        }
    }
```

The board[0, r].BackColor = Color.Azure; was an attempt to isolate where the error derives. It generated the same error, so it seems that the button routine knows that 'board' exists but doesn't acknowledge or is unable to access the subscripted elements. The error generated is:

▶   $exception  {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}   System.NullReferenceException

What do I need to do in  order to overcome this difficulty?

Thanks in advance,

Cam

Comment: board is a local variable in Form1_Load() method. Not accessible from button1_Click().

Comment: Just like VB.NET, *where* you declare a variable determines its *scope*

Comment: Thanks, wanndream, but how do I make the variable public so it will be available?

Comment: Where, Disaffected, do I declare the variable so it will be available within the scope of the button?

Comment: Declare it in your `Form1` class, but outside any method.

Comment: Are you sure you weren't declaring another `board` variable somewhere else? I find it surprising that the compiler didn't throw an error in `button1_Click` if the only `board` variable was declared in `Form1_Load`.

Comment: Hello Gabriel, do you mean it should be declared:    public partial class Form1 : Form
        
    { <-after this brace bracket or before?

Comment: Just inside that, yes.

Comment: ...it originally DID throw an error, but I tried to get around that by writing this line into the designer code: private System.Windows.Forms.Label[,] board;

Comment: Okay, I removed my addition to the desinger code and added the array defintion or declaration where you stipulated. And it still throws the same error mentioned in my original post.

Comment: Should I edit the original post and put in the code for the entire program so that you can examine why this might be happening? Would that help?

Comment: Did you remove the definition from `Form1_Load`? If not, then you just have two variables called `board` each in its own scope.

Comment: Oh, I thought I had, but hadn't. That turned the trick, Gabriel. Thank you so much for your kind help! You are wonderful.

Comment: No problem. I wrote this up into an answer with hopefully more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each variable has a scope: the section of code where that variable is valid. If you define it in a method, then the variable can only be used within that method.

So in this case, if you want to use that variable in multiple methods, you need to declare in a scope that encompasses those methods. In this case, that is your `Form1` class - so just inside the declaration of the class, but outside any method.

But you also need to remove the declaration inside `Form1_Load` too, otherwise you'll end up with two variables with the same name and different scopes. They may have the same name, but they will refer to two different places in memory and not hold the same data. When you use `board` inside `Form1_Load` you will refer to the one declared inside that method, and it will be destroyed as soon as the method finishes.